# User input for a counter

Tags: c, algorithm, input

I'm totally new to this and I'm trying to learn by doing. I have some basic skills in c and I've been making small, simple apps for about 2 weeks all by studying other apps and trying to understand how they are built.

I'm trying to make a counter now that is supposed to count people going in or out.

I got everything to work perfectly except for letting the user define the maximum amount. I would like to have the user type in the max amount in the text field and then press a button called start which would give the variable max the value typed in the text box.

Can I get some help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
mx = Max from User;
nrPersons = 0;

While (Userinput is not ExitProgramm) do
{
   if (0 < nrPersons < mx)  // allwoed range
   {
       run your programm that works
   }
   else
   {
       if (nrPersons > mx)  =>  take action

       if (nrPersons < 0)   =>  take action
   }
}
```